# Plotted points in Map doesn't vary based on the price

Tags: r

I plotted some data points on a map. The Map is the bounty King in Washington. I plotted them on the map successfully. My dataset consists of a column called prices. Their values range in between 0-800000.
I created a new column, called MapColor to print the value either as red or blue based on the price value. If price> 400000 red, else blue.

Now when plotting the points in the map, if MapColor is red I need to map it as red points and if not black. This is how I tried it. But the colors are plotting black only. This is what I tried

```
long <- c(47.5112,47.7210   ,47.3684)
lat <- c(-122.257, -122.319, -122.031)
price <- c(287655,456355,662500,234563)

House <- data.frame(long, lat, price)
House$MapColor  <- ifelse(House$price >=400000, "red", "black")

col <- as.character(House$MapColor)

states <- map_data("state")

wa_df <- states %>%
  filter(region == "washington", subregion == 'king')



counties <- map_data("county")
wa_county <- counties %>%
  filter(region == "washington")

wa_base <-
  ggplot(data = wa_df,
         mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +   geom_point(data = House,aes(x = long, y = lat),size = 0.5,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +scale_color_manual(values=col)+
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
#geom_point(data = House, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red")

wa_base + theme_nothing() +
  geom_polygon(data = wa_county, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)  # get the state border back on top
```

[image]

Comment: Could you use `dput(head(House))` and add some results to your question to make this reproducible? In addition, the subregions for Washington state include lopez island, main, etc. so `wa_df` has no records (with King in the filter being the county)

Comment: Hi Kindly check now. I created very few amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

I think long and lat for those example points were reversed. I set the colors as either red or blue as per the description.

It maps the state polygon, then county, then adds the points using `color = House$MapColor`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

lat <- c(47.5112, 47.7210, 47.3684)
long <- c(-122.257, -122.319, -122.031)
price <- c(287655, 456355, 662500)

House <- data.frame(long, lat, price)

House$MapColor <- ifelse(House$price >= 400000, "red", "blue")

wa_df <- map_data("state") %>%
  filter(region == "washington")

wa_county <- map_data("county") %>%
  filter(region == "washington")

ggplot(data = wa_df, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))+  
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)+
  geom_polygon(data = wa_county, fill = NA, color = "black")+
  geom_point(data = House, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat), color = House$MapColor)+
  coord_fixed(1.3)+
  theme_nothing()
```

[image: state of washington with selected points in color]

Comment: Hi Ben.. Thank u so much... It works for me now too.... Really appreciate your help. I'm having another small question. Is there a way for me to zoom the area (Washington)

Comment: Glad it was helpful. There are a number of ways to draw more specific areas. You could change `wa_county` to only include specific counties in the desired area, and not draw the state. Or, instead of using `coord_fixed` you could specify the area of interest in the map using `coord_map` - for example: `coord_map(xlim = c(-125,-120), ylim = c(45, 50))` - then the aspect ratio is determined by those limits set.